# Why do I take more than 2 seconds to just do a transaction?

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have my Hyperledger Fabric working with the docker containers up.
I have my Hyperledger client, writte in Node.js, using the Fabric Node SDK.

I have an API pointer /createEntity that calls the function "createEntity" on the contract with contract.submitTransaction() and writes some data on the Blockchain.

I send the data and I correctly see on the docker logs of the peer that the contract function is invoked correctly and it terminates after just some milliseconds, adding the new data inside the Blockchain.
But it tooks around 2 seconds to actually respond to the Node.js server that the transaction has been done and the data is written.
So, my Node.js server is waiting for answers for 2 seconds.

Just to have some timings:

This is printed by Node.js server as soon as I invoke the createEntity API:
**Create Entity: 2019-07-08T13:29:28.781Z**

This is printed by the docker logs of Hyperledger:
**createEntity  2019-07-08 13:29:28.814697426**

So after some milliseconds the transaction arrives, and in some milliseconds the transaction is created and written on the ledger, in fact I write the timings after the createEntity function on the contract finishes and I have:
createEntity finished at:  2019-07-08 13:29:28.818830574

But the answer to the Node.js server arrives at:
**Transaction has been submitted 2019-07-08T13:29:30.842Z**

Do someone know what is this delay?
I don't want transaction to take 2 seconds, it has to be immediate.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **submitTransaction** function would take its time to finish,as by default the commit listener is enabled.

So it would wait for the data to be committed and then respond back.

You can disable the commitListener by adding `eventHandlerOptions:{strategy:null}` in the connection option while setting up the gateway.

Hope The bellow code snipped would help you out.

```
 let connectionOptions = {
        identity: USER_ID,
        wallet: wallet,
        discovery: { enabled: false, asLocalhost: true },
        eventHandlerOptions: {
             strategy: null
             }
         }

    await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, connectionOptions)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This actually solves my problem. I reduced the execution from 2s to some ms. But what actually change in the logic of the application? Can you please elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: By logic of application if you mean the business logic,then there is no change in the code.what you are basically doing is disabling the commit listener nothing more.The transaction flow would remain the same internally.

Comment: Then, I think I need a better answer here: what is actually the commitListener? What is his role inside my blockchain client and why I should keep it disabled or enabled?

Comment: I would highly recommend you should read the docs for it,here is the link that might help you https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/tutorial-transaction-commit-events.html

Comment: That's clear now. You sorted this out, thanks a lot! In my case, I just have 1 peer, so the strategy: null is enough, but if I have more peers I should use the default one, right?

Comment: Yes you are correct!Can you mark it as Answer if the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the orderer is involved in this as well.

You are telling your peer to write the data, the peer will create the signed proposal which gets to the orderer. If everything is ok then the order responds back and the peer can finally add the data to its copy of the ledger.

It's for this reason that it can't be instant.

Comment: I see your point. But I don't think this can take 2 seconds to complete. It is a very fast operation anyways. Even if the peer has to ask to the orderer if it is ok, it is an immediate answer in my opinion. Also because I have no transaction in my network at the moment, so when I do the first one or the second one, they must be very fast. If it has to verify more transaction instead, I could understand, but not in my situation. do you have a more specific answer?

Answer (score 0):

On the configtx.yml, the file used to create the artifacts, there is a parameter on the orderer section that says

```
BathTimeout: 2s
```

This determines how much time is going to hold a transaction before commiting it to the peer. By default is 2 seconds but you can change it for example

```
BathTimeout: 500ms
```

Of course use it wisely as it may create, depending on the load of your ledger, blocks with one transaction.

The validation of a transaction should be very fast just milliseconds. It depends on the complexity of your chaincode and the load of your peers of course.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but this does not solve this. I have already tried this solution reducing to 1s and to 500ms, but the timing remains the same: my createEntity function takes 2 seconds to receive the result from the blockchain. I think this is not the parameter to modify.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, if anyone hits this issue (as i did) in new Fabric Gateway (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway).

Regular `submitTransaction` waits for commit event from orderer before returning so it takes ~2s in default configuration. I believe `submitTransaction` is there for compatibility reasons.

Actual Fabric Gateway interface right now proposes using `submit` with slightly modified parameter syntax of `submit(transactionName: string, options?: ProposalOptions): Promise<Uint8Array>;`
and equivalent
`submitAsync` with syntax of:
`submitAsync(transactionName: string, options?: Readonly<ProposalOptions>): Promise<SubmittedTransaction>;`.

The `submit` waits for actual block settlement while `submitAsync` returns immidiately and provides further interface to check tx status afterwards, but gives tx expected outcome immidiately.

Example:

```
const result = await contract.submitTransaction(
        'CreateAsset',
        assetId,
        'yellow',
        '5',
        'Tom',
        '1300',
    );
```

now becomes

```
const result = await contract.submit('CreateAsset', {
        arguments: [ assetId, 'yellow', '5', 'Tom', '1300' ],
    });
```

or alternatively, if you don't want to wait for actual block settlement:

```
const result = await contract.submitAsync('CreateAsset', {
        arguments: [ assetId, 'yellow', '5', 'Tom', '1300' ],
    });
```

with additional interface to query the status:

```
const status = await result.getStatus();
if (!status.successful) {
    throw new Error(`failed to commit transaction ${status.transactionId} with status code ${status.code}`);
}
```

cheers!